# How to match 2 query strings from one URL for Wordpress Redirection Plugin

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect, query-string

I want to use the 'Redirection' plugin for WordPress to redirect search URLS to a cleaner URL.

The Redirection plugin's source URL accepts regular expressions.

ONE EXAMPLE OF WHAT I NEED:

I need this search URL:

```
http://www.danceclass.es/?s=&where=Sydney+%28Australia%29&company_category=pole&cat=pole&search_simple=STEP+3+-+Show+details
```

to redirect to:

```
http://www.danceclass.es/pole-sydney
```

but only if `where=Sydney` AND `cat=pole`.

Can a Regular Expressions expert please translate this example into regex code for me?

I'll rinse and repeat for different `where=` AND `cat=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to extract the values of those 2 query parameters, you'll need 2 capturing groups. However the regex also needs to handle different query parameter order i.e `cat` and `where` order can be different

Here is the regex
https://regex101.com/r/gP9pZ0/1

You can use captured groups to form your new url, an example using `sed`'s substitute(s) command:

```
$sed -r 's@^.*where=([a-zA-Z]*).*cat=([^&]*).*|.*cat=([^&]*).*where=([a-zA-Z]*).*$@http://www\.danceclass\.es/\2\3-\1\4@'
http://www.danceclass.es/?s=&where=Sydney+%28Australia%29&company_category=pole&cat=pole&search_simple=STEP+3+-+Show+details
http://www.danceclass.es/pole-Sydney
http://www.danceclass.es/?s=&company_category=pole&cat=pole&search_simple=STEP+3+-+Show+details&where=Sydney+%28Australia%29
http://www.danceclass.es/pole-Sydney
$
```

Once you the your final URL, you can make the string lowercase which meets your answer. The 2 inputs given to sed have different order i.e 1st URL has `where` then `cat`, order is reverse for 2nd URL

No need to iterate over different values, you can match as per the valid chars mentioned in regex, i.e.:

`cat=[^&]`   cat value will give you every char until it doesn't find `&`
`where=[a-zA-Z]`   where value will give you every char if it is an uppercase/lowercase char